# Wrong value of height (100%) for inner div, if I set border

Tags: html, css

I have simple task with two div. I need that both have colored borders and inner div must use all space. Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
   .d1{ width:150px;height:150px;border:solid 10px black;background:red;}
   .d2{ height:100%; width:100%; border:solid 20px blue; background:green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class=d1>
       <div class=d2>some text</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But browser (IE, Chrome) do not catch that I set borders and  'divs' to show with  artifacts.

Anybody catch this bug?

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    .d1{ width:110px;height:110px;border:solid 10px black;background:blue; padding: 20px;}
    .d2{ height:100%; width:100%; background:green;}​
</style>
```

I think that gives you the effect you're after, basically replacing the border on .d2 by using a background colour on .d1, adding padding to .d1 to act as a border of sorts.

If you add any margin or padding to .d2 it's going to add to the 100% height and width values which means they'll overflow.

Hope that makes sense.

edit: note how I've compensated for a padding of 20px by reducing the height and width by 40px (because it will add padding on both left and right and also top and bottom, making for 40px additional width and height)

Comment: No need to give 'width: 100%' :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know width and height of parent div, you can set correct styles for the children, without percentage, so this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qnxR4/) may do a work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Borders aren't included in your width/height, then your 150x150 will "become" a 170x170 with a 10px border.

Two solutions :

1. Take borders in account, increasing your div width/height
2. Use more divs, and forgot borders

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samsamX/56Egb/1/) to show you both solutions

Answer (score 0):

Because you specified borders thickness the height and width will not take that into account to show nested inside the borders. A solution for your problem if I understand it correctly you can achieve as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<style type='text/css'> 
   .d1{ width:150px;height:150px;overflow:auto;border: solid 10px black;background:red;} 
   .d2{ height:73%; width:73%;border: solid 20px blue; background:green;} 
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div class="d1"> 
       <div class="d2">some text</div> 
   </div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are having issues with the [Html box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/).

you can either figure out the maths your self or depending on which browsers you have to support there is the new "box-sizing" css style which changes how the box model works.

here is a fiddle showing how it can be used:

http://jsfiddle.net/EHUab/